# Start Process from .NET Web Application with Impersonalisation

Tags: asp.net, process, executable, windows-authentication, impersonation

I try to call an .exe file from a webapplication. 
But I want the file called by the user that is impersonalisated by windoes authentication from the website.

```
Process process = new Process();
try
{
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigData.PVDToBudgetDBexePath;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    process.Start();
    log.Info("Process started by " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name +  " with ID: " + process.Id);
    process.WaitForExit();
    log.Info("After WaitForExit Process ID: " + process.Id);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("Error executing file with message " + ex.Message);
}
```

Both info log texts are logged correctly. There is no error occuring. 
But the called Program does not do anything. No logging, no writing in Database.
The user has executable rights on the file.

When I call the same Code from Development Server it works fine.

I use .Net 4.5 and IIS 7 
I found posts concerning this topic only for very old versions of .Net and IIS and that could not help me.

What am i doing wrong?
Or how can I find out whats going wrong?

many thanks,

EDIT:
To better make clear what I intend: 
I have this (self made) exe file  that imports Data from Excel Sheets into a Database. That needs some time. While doing this it logs its Progress whith log4net also into the database.
I want an UI (web application) were the user can trigger the import. 
on this UI there is also an ajax progressbar that shows the progress of the import takten from the log table in the database.

I want maximum one instance of this import process to run in the same time. So I have a function that checks wheter the process is still running. 
If so it does not allow to start another process. If not you can start it again.

```
    private bool IsRunning(string name)
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(name).Length > 0  )
        {
            return true; 
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem now by starting the exe file via TimeScheduler.

path = filepath to the exe file

arguments = arguments to start the exe file with

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;


            using (TaskService taskService = new TaskService())
            {
                var taskDefinition = taskService.NewTask();
                taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Author = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Runs exe file";


                var action = new ExecAction(path, arguments);
                taskDefinition.Actions.Add(action);

                taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("NameOfTask", taskDefinition);

                //get task:
                var task = taskService.RootFolder.GetTasks().Where(a => a.Name == "NameOfTask").FirstOrDefault();

                try
                {
                    task.Run();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error("Error starting task in TaskScheduler with message: " + ex.Message);
                }


            }
```

Comment: P.S. My IsRunning Method (see question) still works with that soution.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by development server the web server that is launched by Visual Studio, than this gives you a false test case since that server is launched by Visual Studio and uses your Windows account to run, while a standard configured IIS does not run under a "user" account but a very limited system account (luckily !!). Even if the user is logged in with a domain account in your website, the IIS process will not run under this account (that wouldn't make sense anyway). That is the reason why this code will not run in IIS and will run in your development server. Even if  you get the exe to launch, it will run using the system account of IIS since you didn't supply any account, which is a limited account which will again run the exe different than you expected.

You will have to use impersonation, if  you really want to go this way, but you will have to launch that process "impersonating" the user that is logged in in the website, asuuming that user account used to login even makes sense at that point. E.g. if it is a domain account, this might work, but if you use some other kind of authentication, like forms authentication, this has no meaning on OS level and thus you cannot use those credentials for impersonation in IIS.

In my experience, and I have done this a few times, impersonation in IIS is always a bad thing and is always creating issues, the same goes for launching command line process by the way.Luckily there is always a better/alternative solution when you think about it. Also the wait for a process to end in your code is not really a good practice. What if the process blocks? It will block website.

Luckily there is always a better/alternative solution when you think about it. A better/possible solution here is to use message queuing for example, where you just push a message to execute the task, and on the other end an application which processes the messages, which might use this command line tool then. That application can run under any user account you want, without you having to let IIS run under a different account. Later on you must of course come back to find the result of the operation, but that can be done using a callback in the background of your website. though this solution is a little bigger than what you are trying to do, it will have a better result on almost every field (responsiveness of your site, maintainability, scalability,..) the only thing where it is worse is the lines of code that you will need, but that is seldomly a valid factor to take into account

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will read about the message queue and try to understand what that is. I added some further explanation in my question to make clear what I want to do. If I would knew the account that throu IIS is trying to start the exe file I could give it the rights and test if it works with hat account. That would bring me a step further.  Or is there any way to give the Credentials from the user to the process starter?

Comment: Do you have the option to modify the application that does the excell processing?

Answer (score 0):

If you write the appplication for excel processing yourself, you can use a table in the DB as some kind of queue instead of using a message bus. Your web application then just needs to add rows with all necesarry info for the process in that table, the status and progress being one of them. Extend your processing application to monitor this table continuously and as soon as it detects a new record, it can then start to do the necessary task and update the db accordingly progress and status and end result). This avoids the messaging sub-system, will work equally good and will avoid you to have to launch a process with impersonation, which was the evil thing to start with.

You can modify the excel process to a windows service so that it runs continuously and starts with the system, but, if you don't want to, there are also tools to run any command line application as a windows service).

This technique would be much easier than the impersonation and allows your website to run in it's protected environment

Comment: thanks for your answer. I guess Windows Servies would be a possibility too. I now solved it via TimeScheduler.